# Mapping databases for new login

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, smo

I need to create a new login in SQL Server 2005 using SMO.

I create the new login using this code :

```
ServerConnection connection = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(Server, Server_UserName, Server_Password);
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server sqlServer = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(connection);

// Creating Login
Login login = new Login(sqlServer, "loginName");
login.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
login.Create("loginPassword");
login.AddToRole("sysadmin");
login.AddToRole("serveradmin");
```

and now I need that all the databases in the user mapping tab (in SQL Server Management Studio) will be checked....

How do I do it in SMO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping a user to all DataBases :

```
 public static void MapUserToAllTheDatabases(String Server, String Server_UserName, String Server_Password, String LoginName,String user_Username)
    {
        ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(Server, Server_UserName, Server_Password);
        Server srv = new Server(conn);
        DatabaseCollection dbs = srv.Databases;
        foreach (Database d in dbs)
        {
            bool ifExists = false;
            foreach (User user in d.Users)
                if (user.Name == user_Username)
                    ifExists = true;

            if (ifExists == false)
            {
                User u = new User(d, user_Username);
                u.Login = LoginName;
                u.Create();
                u.AddToRole("db_owner");
            }
        }
        srv.Refresh();
    }
```